# Handling large volume of data load to redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, bulk-load

We have a 3 node ra3.16xlarge redshift cluster that has to be loaded with 1.5-2 billion records per day. However, it is failing to do so and spilling a lot of data to disk, preventing other queries from execution. All best practices for table design have been followed, is there any suggestion to improve the data load performance?

Comment: What does "failing to do so" mean?

Comment: The load gets stuck on the cluster and runs for more than 3 hrs. If there is any other job on the cluster then, everything gets clogged as this job spills a lot to disk. And we have to manually unclog the cluster and re-run the load.